# Error on ActiveSelection.Tasks

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, ms-project

Does anyone know what this means

```
Set oProjTasks = ActiveSelection.Tasks
```

I have a macro that generates status reports from MS project and exports them directly into MS Word. It is a slick tool when it works.

When I run it now it throws "runtime error '424': object required" at this point.

How do I fix this?

Comment: runtime error '424':  object required

Answer (score 2):

The code that you are displaying is a set statement, that is setting the object ProjTasks equal to the task that is selected in the message box. The ActiveSelection property returns a selection object that represents the active selection. 
It could be that you are experiencing an issue where there are no items selected, in which case it will throw a trappable error code 424. There is a code snippet that you can modify from the MSDN that will work to prevent this type of error from occuring.

Here is the link to the MSDN article... just remember to not use this code verbatim, but modify it to work with your macro.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa169315%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: I am not sure how to integrate this into the macro

Comment: If you can post the macro code, I can follow up with you and show you how the code would be integrated.

Comment: It is a big macro. I would have to mail it to you in text form or as an attachment .bas file. too big for this comment tab

Comment: i reied an experimrnt and changed all activeselection lines to active project. macro ran but then stalled later at this point

Answer (score 0):

You could try just wrapping the error check around the set statement. I've written a small macro on a non-empty project file:

```
Sub Testing()
  On Error GoTo ActiveSelectionErrHandler:
  Set oProjTasks = ActiveSelection.Tasks
  If oProjTasks Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No tasks in current project"
  End If
ActiveSelectionErrHandler:
  Set oProjTasks = ThisProject.Tasks 'or something like that
  Resume Next
End Sub
```

This handles the error but as Steve has already expressed more work is required to integrate the code.

You will have to follow the code to make changes to handle oProjTasks being empty where it is expected to have some values. Otherwise you will see more errors perhaps where the oProjTasks is found to be empty.

Another alternative solution could be to launch the macro after selecting a project as the code you have quoted will work fine if something is selected.

Comment: Part of macro:                                                    Private Sub CalcReportData() Set oProjTasks = ActiveProject.Tasks(1) ActlWork = oProjTasks.ActualWork / 60 TotActlWork = TotActlWork + ActlWork FilterApply Name:="MS BL Fin" SelectSheet Set oProjTasks = ActiveSelection.Tasks MSBLFinish = oProjTasks.Count FilterApply Name:="MS Schd Fin" SelectSheet Set oProjTasks = ActiveSelection.Tasks MSSchdFinish = oProjTasks.Count FilterApply Name:="MS Actl Fin" SelectSheet Set oProjTasks = ActiveSelection.Tasks

Comment: Hi Ron. Have you tried using [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or some such service to share the code?

Comment: Can others get code from there? I have never used it. Would it not be easier to just to email it?

Comment: In response to Nishant Sharma: i am running the macro out of the same file i am trying to get the status report on. how do I "select" the project?

Comment: I tried an experiment. i changed all the entries from eactiveselection. to activeproject and it ran but then syalled out at a new point: