# How to check if a filter has any results?

Tags: vba, filter, ms-project

I apply multiple filters (defined in an array), run through them and export pdfs.

When a filter has no value the code stops because there is nothing to export.

I am using `On Error Resume Next` but this is not sustainable. If the error happens twice it breaks again.

How can I check if the filter has any results?

```vb
For i = 1 To 18

    FilterApply name:=FL(i)
    
    names = ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.name & " " & FL(i)
    
    DocumentExport FileName:="C:\temp\" & names, FromDate:="01/07/22 6:00", ToDate:="15/07/22 18:00", FileType:=pjPDF
        
Next
```

Comment: ??? Use `On Error Resume Next` Then `If Err.Number = 0 Then` ... do your stuff `Else Err.Clear`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. quite easy actually!

```
    **SelectTaskField Row:=0, Column:="name"
    
    If ActiveCell.Text <> "" Then**
```

```html
For i = 1 To 18

    FilterApply name:=FL(i)
    
    SelectTaskField Row:=0, Column:="name"
    
    If ActiveCell.Text <> "" Then

        If Left(FL(i), 1) = "_" Then ' create file name
            names = ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.name & " " & Mid(FL(i), 2, Len(FL(i)))
        Else
            names = ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.name & " " & FL(i)
        End If
        
        
        DocumentExport FileName:="C:\temp\" & names, FromDate:="01/07/22 6:00", ToDate:="15/07/22 18:00", FileType:=pjPDF
        
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I've [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69727438/ms-project-vba-how-to-avoid-errors-when-a-filter-returns-nothing/69730848#69730848) on here before. I recommend creating a separate function to check if the Filter is empty, like this:

```
Public Function CurrentFilterHasTasks() As Boolean

   Dim result As Boolean
   On Error GoTo ErrHandler

   Application.SelectAll 'select everything in the current filter

   'Application.ActiveSelection.Tasks will fail if there are only blank rows in the active selection
   If Application.ActiveSelection.Tasks.Count > 0 Then
        result = True
   End If

   CurrentFilterHasTasks = result

   'call exit function here so the code below the error handler does not run
   Exit Function

ErrHandler:
   result = False
   CurrentFilterHasTasks = result
    
End Function
```

Then you can call the method in your code:

```
For i = 1 To 18

    FilterApply name:=FL(i)
    
    If CurrentFilterHasTasks Then
       names = ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.name & " " & FL(i)
    
       DocumentExport FileName:="C:\temp\" & names, FromDate:="01/07/22 6:00", ToDate:="15/07/22 18:00", FileType:=pjPDF
    End If
        
Next
```